# Word Count through Find function returns different results than Macro

Tags: vba, ms-word, ms-office

I have a word count function that looks for text that is either Highlighted or Bold and Un-Underlined and then returns the number of words in a document that meet that criteria.

However the results differ from the results returned by the Find function in word by a significant margin, anyone have any idea why the discrepancy might be occurring? Am I double-counting something?

```
Sub CountWords()

Dim rngWords As Range
Set rngWords = ActiveDocument.Content
Dim boldCount As Long, highlightCount As Long
Dim wordTotal As Long

Do
With rngWords.Find
    .Highlight = True
    .Forward = True
    .Execute
End With
If rngWords.Find.Found = True Then
    highlightCount = highlightCount + rngWords.Words.Count
Else
    Exit Do
End If
Loop

Set rngWords = ActiveDocument.Content

Do
With rngWords.Find
    .Font.Bold = True
    .Highlight = False
    .Font.Underline = wdUnderlineNone
    .Forward = True
    .Execute
End With
If rngWords.Find.Found = True Then
    boldCount = boldCount + rngWords.Words.Count
Else
    Exit Do
End If
Loop
wordTotal = boldCount + highlightCount
MsgBox "There are " & wordTotal & " words to be spread"
End Sub
```

Comment: Please show us some document phrase which exemplify miscalculation problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Words property counts punctuation and paragraph marks.  Change

```
highlightCount = highlightCount + rngWords.Words.Count
```

to

```
highlightCount = highlightCount + rngWords.ComputeStatistics(wdStatisticWords)
```

and they will match.